# Facing issue in hiding template using hide() in Anjular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two popup's(different template) which is in same controller, The first popup has a button to show the second popup(also first popup btn get's disabled) and when I close second popup, the first popup get enabled again and everything works fine at first , but next time when I click open second popup by clicking first popup btn the second popup doesn't get closed by clicking close btn.

**Inside controller**

```
 //Both are in the same controller--- from first template
  $scope.firstPopUpButton=function(){  
      $scope.filterParams.enableFilter=true; //Disables the first button
      var html1 = $compile('<div  class="panel-report-js" id="classFilter"><div  style = "min-width: 277px !important; position: absolute;top:53px !important;left:-50px !important; background:#FFF;"><div ng-include="reportsTemplate.filterPopupLeft"></div></div></div>')($scope);
      angular.element('#menu-container').append(html1);      
    }
 //close the second popup--- from second template
    $scope.secondPopUpClosebtn=function(){
        var leftPopupCancle=angular.element(document.querySelector('#classFilter'));
        $scope.disableLeftFiltr=false;
        leftPopupCancle.hide();
    }
```

**Templates**

```
angular.module("secondPopup.tpl.html", []).run( function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("class-filter-popup-left.tpl.html",
    "   <a href=\"#\" class=\"filter-cancel side-by-side\" data-ng-click=\"cancelPopup()\">cancel second pop up</a>");
})
angular.module("firstPopup.tpl.html", []).run( function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("class-filter-popup.tpl.html",
 "     <input type=\"button\" class=\"filter\" ng-click=\"classFilterPop();disableLeftFiltr=true\" ng-disabled=\"disableLeftFiltr\" value=\"Open second pop up\"/>\n"+
})
.directive('fitlertest', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
     templateUrl: 'class-filter-popup.tpl.html'
  };
})
```

**Main div where we have directive**

```
angular.module("FirstPopUpDirectiveDiv.tpl.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("FirstPopUpDirectiveDiv.tpl.html",
    "<div id=\"standard-adb\" class=\"student-panel reveal-new\" ng-controller=\"commoncontroller\">\n" +
    " <div fitlertest></div>\n" +   
    "</div>"
    );
```

Not able to figure out why the second popup is not closing.

Comment: You're doing it the jQuery way instead of doing it the angular way. Don't do DOM manipulation. Just add the two popups on the page, use `ng-show="showFirstPopup"` on the first popup, and `ng-show="showSecondPopup"` on the second popup, and show/hide the popups by modifying the **model**: `$scope.showSecondPopup = true; $scope.showFirstPopup = false;`. You should not generate HTML dynamically and accessing the DOM from a controller.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?  It's a bit hard to follow and I think there might be an easier way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/3AuxxjX9muP921lqLBqJ?p=preview